# IOS/Objective-C: Unhindered scrolling of tableview created in code (remove rubber band effect)

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, scrollable

I have created a tableview in code as follows:

```
  _myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(160, 80, 140, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _myTableView.delegate = self;
    _myTableView.dataSource = self;
    _myTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
 [self.view addSubview:_myTableView];
```

It largely works as it should with the following exception.  Because the results in the table vary, I manually adjust the height of the tableview so that it only takes up as much space as the returned rows need as follows:

```
-(void) changeTVHeight: (float) height {
//height calculated from number of items in array returned.
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(120, 80, 180, height);
    self.myTableView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

This works great for shrinking the tableview if there aren't that many results.

However, if there are a lot of results, the tableview expands below the visible part of the screen or the keyboard.  In this case, I would like to be able to scroll the Tableview to see the lower rows.

`scrollEnabled` is set to `YES`.

But while it does allow one to scroll a bit, the scroll is resisted so with effort you can scroll a little bit but due to [rubber band effect](https://www.cultofmac.com/489256/bas-ording-rubber-band-effect-iphone/) you cannot get further than a few rows below the screen and you cannot tap on the lower rows.

I am using autolayout in storyboard for much of the screen. The overall screen scrolls fine but this merely moves the tableview anchored to the screen up and down.  There are no constraints on this tableview but it is added as a subview of the view.

My question is how can I make the tableview scrollable so that it scrolls without resistance?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Edit**:

I tried adding the tableView to self.scrollView instead of self.view.  This anchored the tableView to the scrollview so it is possible to scroll the whole screen down and see the bottom of the tableview.  However, this is not ideal because the rest of the screen is empty way down and you can't see the context for the tableview.  (It's an autocomplete for a textfield at top of screen.)

In contrast when the tableview is added to self.view, it is in correct place, it semi-scrolls or bounces.  It just doesn't scroll down to where I need it to scroll.

Comment: Do you increase height of tableview by number of its content?

Comment: I increase it to number of items x 28 so the tableview is always the right height.  It's just I can't scroll to the bottom of it if it extends off the screen.  Nor can I scroll below the keyboard to see what's behind the keyboard if the keyboard is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a limit so that the table view cannot be larger than the view itself. Tableviews are built on UIScrollView and will handle scrolling on their own, you don't need to try to size it manually. The reason the table view bounces but doesn't scroll is because it is extending below the bottom of the screen. It wont scroll because it has already scrolled to the bottom, you just can't see it because it's outside of the superview.

```
-(void) changeTVHeight: (float) height {
    CGFloat limitedHeight = MIN(height, self.view.frame.size.height)
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(120, 80, 180, limitedHeight);
    self.myTableView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Comment: That did it.  I am unfamiliar with the (height1,height2) syntax.  Is that a min and max?

Comment: Also, I think you meant limitedHeight in newFrame=

Comment: user6631314 Yes, MIN(x, y) will return the smaller value of x and y. There is also MAX(x, y) which will return the larger value of X and Y. I updated the newFrame line to use the limitedHeight variable. Good catch.